# Cannot bind to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: regex, powershell, data-mining

```
## Declaire Variables

## File Path Variables
$savePath = $env:TEMP
$sourceFileAccellerator = "C:\ALL_SALES_WITH_uuid_07-09-2014.txt" ##Path to Source File goes here
$sourceFileLineBreaks = $($savePath + "NifaLeadsListCategoriesWLineBreaks.txt")
$categoryOutput = $($savePath + "CategoryParsedforPowerShell.txt")
$categoryOutputXtraSlash = $($savePath + "CategoriesXtraSlash.txt")
$categoryOutputNoNull = $($savePath + "CategoriesNoNULL.txt")
$searchedFile = $($savePath + $exactSearchTerm + "Temp.txt")
$uuidOutput = $($savePath + $exactSearchTerm + "uuid.SQL")
$uuidColumnSQL = $($savePath + $exactSearchTerm + "Table.sql")

## .sql file creation strings

$sqlUpdate = $("UPDATE ADC.dbo.Contacts SET [" + $exactSearchTerm + "] = 1 WHERE NifaID = '")
$columnAddLine1 = "ALTER TABLE ADC.dbo.Contacts"
$columnAdd = $("ADD [" + $exactSearchTerm + "] nvarchar(10)")

## Regex Variables

$uuidRegEx = '[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}'
$categoryRegEX = '(?<=\\)[^\\\r\n]*\\[^\\\r\n]*$'

## Get the original text file and add line breaks to the categories and output to a new file.

Get-Content $sourceFileAccellerator |% {$_-replace "`t","`n"} > $sourceFileLineBreaks

## Look for Categories and pars the last 2 categories

select-string -Path $sourceFileLineBreaks -Pattern $categoryRegEX -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $categoryOutput

##  Cleanup the Categories for input into the ForEach loop.

$job1 = Start-Job { Get-Content $categoryOutput |% {$_-replace "\\\\", "\\\\\\\\"} > $categoryOutputXtraSlash }
Wait-Job $job1
Receive-Job $job1

$job2 = Start-Job { Get-Content $categoryOutputXtraSlash |% {$_-replace '/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "\n\n"} > $categoryOutputNoNull }
Wait-Job $job2
Receive-Job $job2

## Import the SQL Cmdlets

Import-Module SQLPS

## Load the searchFile and run the script on each column

$SearchFile = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg $categoryOutputNoNull
while ($line = $file.ReadLine()) {
Select-String -Path $sourceFile -Pattern $line > $searchedFile
Select-String -Path $searchedFile -Pattern $uuidRegEx -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $sqlUpdate + $_.Value + "';"} > $uuidOutput
## Create the sql script to add a column
Add-Content -Path $uuidColumnSQL -Value $($columnAddLine1 + " " + $columnAdd)
## Run the SQL scripts
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $uuidColumnSQL -OutputSqlErrors $true -ServerInstance DUMPSTER\DB_DEFAULT -QueryTimeout 0
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $uuidOutput -OutputSqlErrors $true -ServerInstance DUMPSTER\DB_DEFAULT -QueryTimeout 0
## Remove Temporary files
Remove-Item $searchedFile
Remove-Item $uuidOutput
Remove-Item $uuidColumnSQL
}
$file.close()
Remove-Item $categoryOutput
Remove-Item $sourceFileLineBreaks
Remove-Item $categoryOutputXtraSlash
```

I'm working on the above script that parses out data from a tab delimited .txt file and and have tested every component of the script and have had success, but when they're combined into a while loop, Powershell is throwing the errors below:

Output:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
6      Job6            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost             Get-Content $category...
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

8      Job8            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost             Get-Content $category...
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\CategoryParseAndSQLUpdate.ps1:53 char:8
+ while ($line = $file.ReadLine()) {
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\CategoryParseAndSQLUpdate.ps1:66 char:1
+ $file.close()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use jobs (e.g. with `Start-Job` cmdlet) you have to look carefully at the scope of variable(s). Depending on the version: you can either:

- access variable from parent scope with `$using:VariableName` (v. 3+)
- use `ArgumentList` parameter from `Start-Job` and `param()` block inside script block

**EDIT**

Just noticed: I can't see where you define `$file` - looks like it's missing?

Comment: Thanks for catching the $file variable.  From what I think you're saying on using Jobs in powershell (v4) I need to call start the job, wait, then receive like this:
`
$job1 = Start-Job...
$job2 = Start-Job...

$job1
Wait-Job $job1
Receive-Job $job1

$job2
Wait-Job $job2
Receive-Job $job2`

Comment: Important part: `Start-Job { Get-Content $using:categoryOutput ... }` - you should apply this pattern any time you are referencing variable defined in parent scope.

Comment: Ah i never had used the $using.. before.  Thanks!  I had to change where the $job variables were set, but that + the $using fixed the issue.